# Python - Remove parts after keyword for multiple text files with a loop

Tags: python

I have several thousands of text files from which I want to extract a certain portion and save to a different file.

My files might look like this:
***ABC

Text

Text Text***
DEF
GHI

I always want to delete everything starting from "DEF" (so keep the bold italic part) and save back to the file. I have come up with some first code, but I am missing a time-efficient way and also don't know how to get this into a loop. Any suggestions?

```
import fileinput

with open('testfile.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == '': 
            break
    for line in input_data:  
        if line.strip() == 'DEF':
            break
        print (line)
```

Comment: You could try something along the lines of `input_data.read().split('DEF')[0]`

Comment: Why GHI is not bold?

Comment: Your first loop basically does nothing. It checks for a condition every time - if it's true, the loop stops and if it's false, the loops continues until it reaches the end of the file. What you want to do is remove the second `for line in input_data` since you want all your logic in a single loop.

Comment: _I have come up with some first code, but I am missing a time-efficient way_ Time-efficient way of doing what?